# Finding shapes in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, shapes

Everything i have researched for API regarding shapes is all with adding shapes, is there a way to find a shape based on certain boundaries you create? What i'm actually wanting to do is find houses near you on google maps. and highlight each house/building with lines. The lines being created is not the problem the problem is finding out the algorithm to actually find shapes

Comment: You meant you want API for house boundary data?

Comment: Yes! Is there already API for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want the shapes of the buildings/houses/complexes for the area?

Comment: @KayAnn I would like to know how to do this.  I want the person to enter their address and for their house to be highlighted.

Comment: To do this:

1) Make kml layer of the base map which has these area shapes. House, building etc.
2) Then make markers or make radius for the locations. Geofencing API
3) Once the desired marker or Geofence is hit, you can then highlight the shapes on the layer of the map.

Comment: That's just one of the ways you can approach it. There are more than one for sure.